# How do I disable notifications in Adium?

Tags: macos, adium

I feel a bit dumb asking this, but I've scoured the preferences and can't find any option about how to disable the built-in notifications (ie, not growl) which are shown when a contact comes online.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.6, latest version of Adium.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for Preferences --> Notifications (I guess this will be the english term in the menu).

[image]

Here you can not only add and delete sound and growl notifications, but also any other alerts.

Comment: Thanks! Still seems a bit weird that they would call this option "growl notifications" instead of just "notifications", as those route through growl if available. Anyways, got it sorted out.